# Book about a hive of people behaving like insects?

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember a story about a sinister organization that controlled people in some sort of hive. The authorities investigate it but underestimate the problem initially, thinking it's just some sort of cult.

They might have had vats to recycle people?

I specifically remember a part about a female hive agent trying to seduce information from an investigator, they have sex and he dies of a heart attack - his colleague wonders about what kind of weapon was used.

Comment: I know you have accepted an answer, but for the sake of other visitors who may be looking for different books with similar themes, this description sounds a little reminiscent of Stephen Baxter's *Destiny's Children* series, which starts with *Coalescent*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Frank Herbert's [Hellstrom's Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellstrom%27s_Hive).

[image: front cover]

> America is a police state, and it is about to be threatened by the most hellish enemy in the world: insects.
>
> When the Agency discovered that Dr. Hellstrom's Project 40 was a cover for a secret laboratory, a special team of agents was immediately dispatched to discover its true purpose and its weaknesses—it could not be allowed to continue. What they discovered was a nightmare more horrific and hideous than even their paranoid government minds could devise.
>
> First published in Galaxy magazine in 1973 as "Project 40," Frank Herbert's vivid imagination and brilliant view of nature and ecology have never been more evident than in this classic of science fiction.
> <sub>-[Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53729.Hellstrom_s_Hive)</sub>

Comment: This book terrified me as a child.  (Probably because it was't intended to be read by a child...)

Comment: That's it! Thanks.